# Selenium: How to select nth button using the same class name

Tags: java, selenium, screen-scraping

I am trying to select the 3rd button using the css class "btnProceed"

```
    <input type="button" class="btnProceed" value=" " onclick="SecuritySubmit(false,'https://somewebsite.com/key=xxyyzz');return false;">
```

My code is as follows:

```
    WebElement query_enquirymode = driver.findElement(By.className("btnProceed"));
    query_enquirymode.click();
```

I can only select the 1st element using "btnProceed"

Is there a way to select the 3rd button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.className("btnProceed"));
WebElement query_enquirymode = buttons.get(2);
query_enquirymode.click();
```