# Handling an onclick event inside div tag using selenium java

Tags: javascript, selenium

How do I handle this `div` using Selenium?

```
<div onclick="Hover_Menu();Toggle_LevelToolMenu(this,event);" 
     class="edittop edit-one"></div>
```

I want to click on this and work with the menu that will be displayed. I believe I will be able to handle the menu that is display, however, I am not able to click on this `div`.

I tried using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
```

Thought I would use JavascriptExecutor but `getElementbyId` will not work since this is `div` and there is no ID associated

Example:

```
<div style="height:25px; width:55px;">
    <div onmouseover="Hover_ToolBarMenu();" class="edit_box">
        <div onclick="return Click_ToolBarMenu('Edit',1019, 9189707,event, this)" class="editopt edit">
            Edit
        </div>
        <div onclick="Hover_LivesMenu();Toggle_ToolBarMenu(this,event);" class="editopt edit-dot dot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div style="display:none; position:relative;" class="qm_ques_level_menu">
        <div onmouseover="Hover_LivesMenu();" onclick="return Click_ToolBarMenu('Delete',1019, 9189707,event, this)" class="menu_buttons img_ico del">
            Delete
        </div>
        <div onmouseover="Hover_LivesMenu();" onclick="return Click_ToolBarMenu('Copy',1019, 9189707,event, this)" class="menu_buttons img_ico copy accor">
            Copy <span class="arrowIcon">?</span>
        </div>
        <div onmouseover="Hover_LivesMenu();" onclick="return Click_ToolBarMenu('Move',1019, 9189707,event, this)" class="menu_buttons img_ico move accor">
            Move <span class="arrowIcon">?</span>
        </div>
        <div onclick="return Click_ToolBarMenu('Deposit2QB',1019, 9189707,event, this)" class="menu_buttons img_ico qb">
            Deposit to Bank
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div onclick="Hover_LiveMenu();Toggle_ToolBarMenu(this,event);" class="editotp edit-one"></div>
this is the div tag I am working with

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to read with selenium? Its difficult you know what `this div` is referring to

Comment: @BountyHunter, I recommend that you edit the question with the new code and proper formatting. Don't just add it to a comment (impossible to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I used jQuery for invoking the onclick function in this div

Below is the jQuery I used

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');$('.editopt.edit-dot').get(0).onclick(event)
```

Thanks everyone who posted and helped me on this.

Answer (score 0):

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html

can you not use `CLASS_NAME`

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'edit-one')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('edit-one')
```

Comment: There are a lot of other elements using the same class. So cannot really use this. If I store  it in an array using class name, I will not be able to find the instance I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

[Find and click an item from 'onclick' partial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691126/find-and-click-an-item-from-onclick-partial-value)

How about something like this?

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[onclick*='Hover_Menu']")
```

Comment: Tried it, did not help

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium: How to select nth button using the same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044075/selenium-how-to-select-nth-button-using-the-same-class-name)

How about this one (would required the div to be in a static position)

```
var nth = 2;
var divs = driver.findElements(By.className("edit-one"));
var div = divs.get(nth);
div.click();
```